# Removing shower rail

Tags: shower, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

Having some issues locating or figuring out how to remove a shower rail rod from the wall to replace.

It looks as if it has hex slots to remove on the two attachments, however a 1.5mm hex doesn’t fit- is it probably a smaller fit, or is there something simple I’m missing to remove it?[image]

Inlined photoshop cleanup of [unregistered] OP's screw head

[image]

Comment: Looks like an allen key - all you need to do is find the right one. 1.5mm is tiny & unlikely to be used in this situation. If you're EU, 3 or 4mm would be most common, idk for US.

Comment: It is nice to have a set of metric and standard allen keys.  Just keep trying till one fits in nice and solid.  There might be dirt/rust in that head also that should be cleaned out.

Comment: Believe it or not, @Tetsujin, my metric wrenches & hex keys have _far_ more use than any of my SAE ones. :D

Comment: @FreeMan - I bought a set of each maybe 25 years ago. I don't think I've used the imperial once, but I am in the UK where we talk in feet but have to buy things in metres ;)

Comment: I feel sorry for you Brits - your units of measure are so confused. You buy a liter (oops... litres) of milk, but a pint of beer; measure distance in kilometers, but measure speed in miles per hour; and, of course, you still measure weight in stone... :D

Comment: @FreeMan - Officially, the mile & a pint of beer in a pub got a free pass. Everything else is metric… officially. So our road signs are still in miles, consequently we still use miles per gallon, though we buy fuel in litres; our pubs sell draught beer in pints, but nothing else. Buy it in a can/bottle it's in litres.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to look in the holes to see if it's really a hex, or a Torx, or a flathead or some other drive on the setscrew.

Poking in a hex and hoping it fits is only going to work in the limited situation where that's the right thing in the right size.

Depending how long it's been there, you may also need penetrating oil as showers are great places for hardware to corrode, and manufacturers often don't spend the minuscule differential cost on corrosion-resistant hardware. By the time you want to remove it they don't care how difficult that is.

Comment: And if the penetrating oil doesn't work, heating it up with a good hot torch may help break corrosion free.